# Convert comma separated twitter user-ids to corresponding screen names

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

I am developing a twitter application. The Twitter Followers API will return 5000 user-ids at a time as comma separated string. I need to pull the screen-name, followers count and following count from userlookup API. But this API will pull user details of 100 ids at a time.

Can anybody please help me in finding the most efficient/recommended way of breaking the comma separated string to batches of 100 userids and getting the user details?

Comment: What API? Can't you use a wrapper like http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Comment: @AmarPalsapure - I am using .net 3.5.

Comment: @gideon - Thanks for the API. I need to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do, split happens only once.

```
   string ids = "YOUR IDs";
   int limit = 100;
   List<string[]> store = new List<string[]>();
   var split = ids.Split(',');
   int counter = 0;
   while (true) {
       var batch = string.Join(",", split.Skip(counter++ * limit).Take(limit));
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(batch)) break;
       //Make your call here
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use result.Split(",").Take(100) this will split the whole thing into an array and then take the top 100 results. If this doesnt perform fast enough you should manually stream the string to only read the first 100 commas. This will be slightly faster but not as syntactically elegant. In the first case you should still be able to process 5000 comma separated elements in a fraction of a second on any modern machine.

Comment: I have also thought of same way. But I was not sure about the performance. I will go for this way of execution. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you find it doesnt meet your performance needs try the stream approach which will technically be faster